# How to disable status messages?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I am creating/updating terms and nodes dynamically using code. It shows a lot of status message as usual. But I need to hide those message only for this task. That means if any user creates/updates terms or nodes it will show the status message.

How can I do that? Please note that the task will run by cron, so a lot of status massage will be stacked for display. Obviously nobody wants to be the poor person to see the huge list of status messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look to Disable Messages module http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages I think that could be useful for your needs.

> Features
>
> ```
> * Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
> * Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
> * Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from any role.
> * Disable all filtering for specific users.
> * Disable all filtering for specific paths.
> * Apply filtering only for specific paths.
> * Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the end users.
> ```

Comment: That a good one. I think looking into it's code will be helpful. May be it can be use with corn job without altering this module. Thank you :)